# What kind of footage is this and where can I get it?

Tags: greenscreen

Can someone help me identify what kind of stock footage is [this](https://imgur.com/a/4BxgvmR), I wish to swap out the text and the image on the stage for someone else. Is it green screen footage or an opener?

Where can I get similar footage? I have had a google and to be honest I dont know what to google green screen stage footage?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an "intro", but if you want to personalize it you can not look it as footage.

Footage has all the elements fixed. You need to look for a template, where the elements, like the text, can be actually edited and then rendered again into a clip.

Examine the example, the perspective is actually matching the camera movement, so the template needs to be a 3D template.

You could make your own in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) the best free 3D program, but this requires time.

You can look for some projects using these keywords: [blender 3d intro template](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=blender%203d%20intro%20template)

If you have the adobe's subscription plan, look for "After effects 3D intro template".

There can be as other answer posted a Cinema3D template, but the program itself is quite expensive. It also has some monthly plans.

---

There can actually be some "footage" with some green screen areas, but the look would be different, for example the green area could be used to reveal a background, but this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to find a template for AE cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a (to be honest, quite old looking) 3D-Animation. I believe that looking into something like 3dsmax, Maya, Modo or Cinema4D might be the best bet for you. Otherwise you can search for "talent show display opener" as a Cinema4D template.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could change the screens simply by using any effects editor (ex: Adobe After Effects) that has tracking, which will allow you to pseudo 3D map the screens with motion but one major problem is the spotlight going over the screen.  You'll have to just fake it by putting a mask over the light and filling it colored or white.  With more work you might be able to recreate it.

You can find many tutorials on YouTube such as this one: